# Can ReactJS run without node in Symfony 5.3 using their Webpack Encore Bundle

Tags: reactjs, symfony

Right now I'm building an application where I use Symfony 5.3 as a full stack framework. So I use twig for my views and vanilla javascript. At first this wasn't a big problem but I had to build a few multi step forms and it's starting to be really annoying. Although I'm new to frontend frameworks I want to give ReactJS a try. After some searching I found Symfony's Encore bundle. The only problem that I have is that the hosting server does **NOT** have NodeJS installed.

Is it possible to use React (with Encore) without node running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reactjs app is a list of static js and css files that don't require nodejs to be run, but nodejs is required to build react application